# How to decrypt HTTPS packet

Tags: go, encryption, https

With Go I can get http packets using gopacket, I have a certificate I want to obtain https packets, but I can't decrypt the package?

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#example_Config_keyLogWriter

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the TCP packets the same way, there won't be much difference, but obviously the payload (at least) will be encrypted.

To decrypt them, you could wrap them in a type that implements `net.Conn` and then use `crypto/tls` to read. It's not a small interface though.

Otherwise you can implement the decrypt function yourself, with the code from `crypto/tls` as an example: https://golang.org/src/crypto/tls/conn.go?s=38163:38205#L318

Comment: hey, didn't want to open a duplicate. can you elaborate a little bit further?